# How to the get the 'Set-Cookie' header in the browser environment using fetch

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch-api

I am login the linkendIn using javascript. After login I am extracting the jsession id from the 'Set-Cookie' header of the response. But when I am trying to use the same code in the extension or in the browser environment I am getting the status code 0 and hence not getting the set-cookie header. So How can I get the Set-Cookie header in the browser environment using fetch. If it is not possible using fetch suggest some alternatives

This is what I have tried till now

```
(async () => {
  const loginPageResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/login');
  const loginPageHtml = await loginPageResponse.text();
  const loginCsrfParamMatches = loginPageHtml.match(/name="loginCsrfParam" value="([^"]+)"/);
  const loginCsrfParam = loginCsrfParamMatches && loginCsrfParamMatches[1];

  const loginFormData = new URLSearchParams();
  loginFormData.append('session_key', 'user@gmail.com');
  loginFormData.append('session_password', 'password');
  loginFormData.append('loginCsrfParam', loginCsrfParam);
  

  const loginResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: loginFormData,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': '*/*',
      'Referer': 'https://www.linkedin.com/home',
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    },
    redirect: 'manual'
  });
  const jsessionId = loginResponse.headers.get('Set-Cookie')
  const jId = jsessionId.match(/ajax:\d+/)[0];
  console.log(jId);
```

I have added this code for the alternative approach using chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener((details) => {
      console.log(details);
      // Check if the request is for the login page
      if (details.url.includes('https://www.linkedin.com')) {
        // Get the JSESSIONID cookie from the response headers
        const jsessionId = details.responseHeaders.find((header) =>
          header.name.toLowerCase() === 'set-cookie' && header.value.includes('JSESSIONID=')
        )?.value.split(';')[0];
        console.log(jsessionId);
      }
    },
    { urls: ['<all_urls>'] },
    ['responseHeaders','extraHeaders']);
```

[and this is the responseHeaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwUAk.png)

Comment: In an extension you can use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived

Comment: I have already tried but still in the response set-cookie is not present - @wOxxOm

Comment: I have added the code please take a look at it - @wOxxOm

Comment: I guess there's no header because your request is treated as cross-origin. Inspect the outgoing headers in devtools or Fiddler/Charles/Wireshark and you'll probably see chrome-extension:// somewhere or some cors stuff or there'll be no `referer`. In such case you can add or modify these outgoing headers by using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.

Answer (score -1):

In the browser environment,it will not include the Set-Cookie header by default. However, you can include the credentials option in the fetch request to specify that cookies should be included.
Change the code as follows:

```js
const loginResponse = await fetch('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: loginFormData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.linkedin.com/home',
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  },
  redirect: 'manual',
  credentials: 'include' // include cookies in the request
});

const jsessionId = loginResponse.headers.get('Set-Cookie');
const jId = jsessionId.match(/ajax:\d+/)[0];
```

Comment: I forgot to add that in the browser same code returning with the status code 0 @Mina